# Apollo server return protected field when performing login mutation

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

I have a problem with returning protected fields from PersonType in the login mutation.
The idea is to set the cookie or session, and then return the user with some protected fields.

Server:

```
  const server = new ApolloServer({
    schema,
    context: async ({ req, res }: { req: Request; res: Response }) => {
      const person = await authenticatePerson(req); //Get user from session or auth header

      return {
        req,
        res,
        person,
      };
    },
  });
```

Resolver:

```
loginCms: {
    type: PersonType,
    args: { data: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(LoginCmsInput) } },
    resolve: async (_, args) => {
      try {
        const personExists = await prisma.person.findUnique({
          where: {
            email: args.data.email,
          },
        });
        //... Other checks
        req.session.user = {
          id: personExists.id.toString(),
          personRoleSubjectId: personExists.PersonRoleSubject[0].id.toString(),
        };
        if (args.data.remember) {
          //14 Days
          req.session.cookie.maxAge = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 14;
        }

        return person;
      } catch (error) {
        throw handleCatchError(error);
      }
    },
  },
```

PersonType

```
//...
 activePersonRoleSubject: {
        type: PersonRoleSubjectType,
        resolve: async (parent, args, { person }) => {
          try {
          //Person is null because the context already resolved before the the login resolver got called, and I cannot update context
            console.log("PERSON", person);
            if (!person?.id) {
              return null;
            }
            if (parent.id === person.id) {
              return person.PersonRoleSubject;
            }
            return null;
          } catch (error) {
            throw handleCatchError(error);
          }
        },
      },
    //...
```

This works when session and cookies are already set, but it doesnt work on the first login call.

There are two solutions that I can think of:

- Return a boolean on successful login, and then fire another query (currentPerson) to return the person with protected fields. This would work but it requires two api calls for every login.
- Return non-protected fields on login, and then query protected fields. Still requires two api calls

Are there any better solutions to this?